# How to reduce renders and memoize a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component that passes an empty object to a child component. The prop is causing a re-render. Is there a way to avoid this?

Parent Component

```
 const user =
      index !== undefined ? form?.user?.[index] ?? {} : {};

 <AddOrEditUserModal user={user}
```

Child

```
const AddOrEditUserModal = ({user}) => {

  const [editedUser, setEditedUser] = useState(user);

  const onChange = (event: onChangeInputEvent) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setEditedUser({
      ...editedUser,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

stakcoverflow, google

Comment: Yes, you can memoize `AddOrEditUserModal` with React.memo. And you'll need to avoid re-creating a new empty object every time. I'd personally pass undefined to the child, and let the child instantiate it to an empty object if not present

Comment: As @AndyRay said, do `<AddOrEditUserModal user={undefined}` from the parent, and `const AddOrEditUserModal = ({user = {}}) => {` in the child.